# Is there any way to display WL.Logger error messages in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, logging, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a Worklight app for Windows Phone 8. When building to the device via Visual Studio 2012, I can see messages logged via the WL.Logger's debug method in the Visual Studio console. However, I can't see any messages which were logged using WL.Logger's error method.

I haven't seen any other consoles in Visual Studio, and the [a WL.Logger documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_logger.html) doesn't provide much help - the only reference to Visual Studio is "Debug messages are displayed in the Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 console." - which conspicuously doesn't mention error messages.

Is there any way to display WL.Logger error messages in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used Visual Studio, so take this with a grain of salt. Maybe you can override the call on windows environments to use whatever logger you want. For example, let's use `console.log`:

```
if (running on windows env) {
   WL.Logger.error = function () {
     console.log.apply(console, arguments); //or alert(...)
  }
}
```

You can get the current environment using the `WL.Client.getEnvironment()` API.

If I had to guess, `console.error` which is what `WL.Logger.error` uses for error messages (assuming it's defined) is not being printed to the console for some reason.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I did some research and found that on initializing a logger you can add a callback which will occur every time a message is called. My solution is to define a callback which, when the environment is Windows Phone 8 and the log priority is error, will print the message out using console.log(). My callback is:



`function(message, priority, pkg) {
if (WL.Client.getEnvironment() === WL.Environment.WINDOWS_PHONE_8 && priority === 'error') {
  console.log(message);
}
}`

 (Apologies. I don't know how to format comments.)